# Drupal7 workflow "publish node" trigger action

Tags: drupal-7

I was configuring my drupal 7 installation.

I made a simple publishing workflow:
Draft->Submit->Public

Now when I go to configuring triggers for the workflow, I want to make the node "published" and "brought to front page" when it moves from Submit to Public

However, the choose action dialog doesn't show me that option. It shows me only one "node" action:
[change workflow state of node to next state]

I was hoping for an option like [publish node] & [bring it on front page]

How do I trigger the node to be published via the workflow trigger config?

Comment: Well the Drupal core actions and triggers system is limited in it's capabilities. There are two options you have. One is to write the missing action yourself or you can use the Rules module (http://drupal.org/project/rules). Rules has the same basic concepts like actions and triggers, but it's much more powerful.

Comment: I used the rules module. Thanks :)

Comment: Or you can apply this patch - http://drupal.org/node/1380954#comment-5700818